# Entidades marcadas como FETCH LAZY estão voltando "null" mesmo após um chamada ao método GET

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa, lazy-loading

Olá, bom dia amigos,

Porquê minhas entidades marcadas como fetch lazy estão voltando "null" mesmo quando são invocadas por meio de um get?

O que eu aprendi em diversos cursos é que ao fazer a primeira chamada a um método get, o hibernate carregaria o objeto do banco de dados, atualizei o hibernate para a ultima versão, mesmo assim continua trazendo "null" do banco de dados, estou utilizando o método .find(), já usei também o .load().

À fins de teste, como uma má prática, eu tentei abrir a transação, e dentro dela carregar o objeto por meio de um get e nada aconteceu!

```
EntityManager manager = HibernateUtil.fabrica.getEntityManager();
cliente = manager.find(Cliente.class, 3);
```

Nesse momento endereço retorna "null" e possivelmente vai gerar um nullPointerException futuramente.

```
Endereco endereco = cliente.getEndereco();
manager.close();
```

Alguém saberia de dizer o que seria isso? se estou configurando errado? se não é bem assim depois do primeiro get? realmente tentei de tudo e quando uso o lazy, gera nullPointerException.

Para piorar, se eu utilizar muito o EAGUER começa a gerar aquela exception de "multiples bags", alguém saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Tem como postar o código do metodo inteiro de consulta?

Comment: Assim que eu chegar em casa, vou copiar e colar o código aqui.

Comment: Você está vendo este "null" pelo debug?

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece, basicamente, por que o Hibernate "não deixa" você acessar o atibuto diretamente.
Ao usar `FetchType.LAZY` em seus atributos, ele cria proxies para eles.

Dessa forma, quando você chama o getter do atributo em questão, a requisição chega nesse proxy e aí sim o Hibernate tenta buscar os dados no banco de dados, mas para isso ele precisa de uma sessão aberta e nessa altura, já não tem mais qualquer sessão aberta e então o atributo fica nulo.

Para resolver isso, você pode atuar de duas maneiras:

1. Mudando o `FetchType` para `EARGER`
2. Seguindo as instruções do [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) sobre como fazer uma espécie de tunning no seu JPA através de um plugin Maven do Hibernate.

---

Observação: a primeira solução é simples, mas pode lhe trazer complicações no futuro, como excesso de consumo de memória e etc.
Já a segunda solução é complexa, mas resolve eu problema, ao que aparenta, da melhor forma possível.

Vale refletir sobre qual solução usar (custo x benefício).

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, assim que chegar em casa vou efetuar o teste e te dou um retorno !!

Comment: o problema é que eu não utilizo o maven e sempre que eu uso em classes mt acopladas o EARGER gera uma exception MultipleBagFetchException.